# ASP.NET MVC: Is it possible to see if where the the request comes from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't want the users to directly access images and media by writing the url to the controller in the browser.

I'm using a Autorhizationfilter to check if the user is logged in and should have access to see the image or media, but is there a way to see if the user is requesting the controller directly via the browser or if the request is embedded in the .cshtml or js-files.

Comment: Sorry, but that just doesn't make sense. If you want to protect images and media files, you should hide them behind AuthorizationFilter too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no way to get a safe protection for this. Referer easily be be faked when using `HttpWebRequest` or similar methods. Referer would work if you just want to protect your images from regular users that doesn't use anything other than a browser.

Another method would be to generate a id for the images which can only be used one time. Instead of writing `<img src="/path/to/image.png" />` you write `<img src="/controller/image/sdlkjdsjlksdlk" />` where `sdlkjdsjlksdlk` is a ID that you map to your image in a session variable. Use [`ImageResult`](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx) to return the image from your controller and delete the ID when the image have been returned.

Comment: Beware that you will loose caching abilities since in this case the image URL will change every time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to check the [referrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) in `Request.UrlReferrer`
This would not be very reliable, though.

Comment: If a link is embedded in a JS-file or something else, there will be no more referrer than when the user types in the address himself/herself. So I do not think this would work in this specific case.

Comment: You're right. I think this would only work if the image is displayed as a img tag in the document and probably won't work if added dynamically on the client side. And then again, it would depend on the browser since it's the one responsible for passing the referrer in the HTTP header. I really don't think there is a good solution for this problem, so I can only suggest some leads...

Answer (score 0):

You might can do this by looking at the StackTrace at run-time through your code, but that's a costly operation and that assumes that the execution paths for both requests are divergent enough to make a determination.